# SQL Server - group by column for each corresponding value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to this forum. Hope fully I will be able to contribute and get my queries resolved too.
I am stuck at this that I do not know where to start off.

I have below data set.

**| Start Step| End  1 | End 2 |**
|    1001866 |    1001867 | NULL       |
|    1001866 |    1001868 | NULL       |
|    1001868 |    1001873 | NULL       |
|    1001873 |    1001868 | NULL       |
|    1001868 |    1005206 | NULL       |
|    1001873 |    1001867 | NULL       |
|    1005206 |    1001873 | NULL       |
|    1005206 |    1005385 | 1005386    |
|    1005206 |    1005377 | 1005378    |
|    1005378 |    1005376 | 1005206    |
|    1005379 |    1005376 | 1005206    |
|    1005379 |    1005380 | 1005381    |
|    1005381 |    1005382 | 1001869    |
|    1005381 |    1005383 | NULL       |
|    1005381 |    1005384 | 1001872    |
|    1005378 |    1005379 | NULL       |
|    1005383 |    1001872 | NULL       |
|    1005383 |    1005376 | 1005206    |
|    1005383 |    1005381 | NULL       |
|    1001869 |    1001871 | NULL       |
|    1005386 |    1005376 | 1005206    |

I want each step to be in single row with their corresponding end1 and end2 and ordered by step and ranked. I want the output to be as in the image:

**| Rank | Start | End Step 1 | End Step 2 |**
|    1 |    1001866 | **1001867**    | NULL       |
|    1 |    1001866 | **1001868**    | NULL       |
|    2 |    **1001867** | NULL       | NULL       |
|    3 |    **1001868** | 1001873    | NULL       |
|    3 |    **1001868** | **1005206**    | NULL       |
|    4 |    1001869 | NULL       | NULL       |
|    4 |    1001869 | 1001871    | NULL       |
|    5 |    1001871 | NULL       | NULL       |
|    6 |    1001872 | NULL       | NULL       |
|    7 |    1001873 | 1001868    | NULL       |
|    7 |    1001873 | 1001867    | NULL       |
|    8 |    **1005206** | 1001873    | NULL       |
|    8 |    **1005206** | 1005385    | 1005386    |
|    8 |    **1005206** | 1005377    | 1005378    |
|    9 |    1005376 | NULL       | NULL       |
|   10 |    1005377 | NULL       | NULL       |
|   11 |    1005378 | 1005379    | NULL       |
|   11 |    1005378 | 1005376    | 1005206    |
|   12 |    1005379 | 1005376    | 1005206    |
|   12 |    1005379 | 1005380    | 1005381    |
|   13 |    1005380 | NULL       | NULL       |
|   14 |    1005381 | 1005382    | 1001869    |
|   14 |    1005381 | 1005383    | NULL       |
|   14 |    1005381 | 1005384    | 1001872    |
|   15 |    1005382 | NULL       | NULL       |
|   16 |    1005383 | 1001872    | NULL       |
|   16 |    1005383 | 1005376    | 1005206    |
|   16 |    1005383 | 1005381    | NULL       |
|   17 |    1005384 | NULL       | NULL       |
|   18 |    1005385 | NULL       | NULL       |
|   19 |    1005386 | 1005376    | 1005206    |
|   19 |    1005386 | 1005387    | NULL       |
|   20 |    1005387 | NULL       | NULL       |

Just highlighted few values for better understanding.

Is it possible ?
Can any one please help ?

Comment: Please provide datasets inline (not screen shots), preferraby with data scripted out into tables so we can use that to test/produce a result

Comment: Here's a good place to start: [Forum Etiquette: How to post data for a T-SQL question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: "Inline" means in the form of DDL and DML!

Comment: Hi Everyone, I am trying to put excel rows in the question..but it is all coming as single row. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi I have just updated the code. Plaese let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does my question make sense now ? I am actually confused if I have provided too much details or bad presentation ..

Answer (score 2):

```
 select dense_rank() over(order by [start step]) [rank], * from  
 (select * from yourtable
 union 
 select distinct [end 1], null, null from yourtable where [end 1] is not null 
  union 
 select distinct [end 2], null, null from yourtable where [end 2] is not null 
 )a order by [start step]
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I just updated my question. Can you please look back again into my problem ? Thanks.

Comment: No. Values in End1 are not appearing in Start Step.

Comment: OK see adjusted - hows this?

Comment: It says, 
Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 459
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.